# Why does PgAdmin III give warning that PgAdmin.exe has disappeared from C drive?

Tags: windows-7, postgresql, pgadmin

So I'm currently working with PostgreSQL, PostGIS, p-mapper, and QuantumGIS to build a web-mapping system. And earlier this morning, I opened PgAdmin III just to check on my database, no editing, no clicking, nothing. Then I set my computer to sleep mode for about an hour -I closed my PgAdmin III-, and when I want to open it again, it gives me warning that PgAdmin.exe's dissappear from my C drive. I checked on Program and Features, my PostgreSQL's still there and then I checked in C drive. PgAdmin.exe went missing completely.

The weirdest thing is, my map's still working. It loads data that supposed to be inside of PgAdmin III. What happened??

*note : my OS's Windows 7*

Comment: PgAdmin is only an administration tool for PostgreSQL; the data isn't "inside" it but in the actual database.

Answer (score 1):

This *reeks* of file-system corruption. I strongly recommend backing up all important data on the system *now*, but not overwriting any existing good backups you have in the process.

Then [schedule a file system check on c:](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/check-your-hard-disk-for-errors) and reboot. When they system comes back up, if it does so without error, also do a SMART test on the drive.

If you don't find anything with that... well, you or a program on your computer *must* have done something to make the change. In the absence of user action, action by another program, or file system / disk problems, files simply do not delete themselves.